# lpc2148 RTC print issue

Tags: c

enter code here

```
void DateTimeConversion (void)
{
  unsigned char TempDay,TempMonth,TempYear,i;
  unsigned char TempHour,TempMinute,TempSecond;
  TempDay=0;TempMonth=0;TempYear=0;TempHour=0;TempHour=0;TempSecond=0;
  col=1;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    sprintf(MyStr,"%c",(unsigned int)StoreUserID[i]);
    ClcdGoto(col,2);ClcdPutS_P(MyStr);
    col++;
  }

  TempDay=((unsigned int)(StoreUserID[6] * 10) + (unsigned int)(StoreUserID[7] * 1));
  TempMonth=((unsigned int)(StoreUserID[8] * 10) + (unsigned int)(StoreUserID[9] * 1));
  TempYear=((unsigned int)(StoreUserID[4] * 10) + (unsigned int)(StoreUserID[5] * 1));
  TempHour   = ((unsigned int)(StoreUserID[0] *10) + (unsigned int)(StoreUserID[1] * 1));
  TempMinute = ((unsigned int)(StoreUserID[2] *10) + (unsigned int)(StoreUserID[3] * 1));
  TempSecond = ((unsigned int)(StoreUserID[4] *10) + (unsigned int)(StoreUserID[5] * 1));
}
```

I am using LPC 2148 for RTC.
description:

1. I have used singlekey to read multiple values(0-9)on same column (2 line LCD display used).
2. The read value is stored in StoreUserId array(as col++ array also increased)
3. Above function is called to save value for SEC,MINUTE,HOUR.
4. StoreUserid is print to crosscheck value enter correctly.
5. But after conversion(check multiply *10) TempSecond, TempMinute, TempHour shows random value after conversion not getting where is issue?.

Comment: I don't understand.  The last six lines don't do anything.

Comment: last six lines are actual variable I used to store values. for loop is used just to cross check whether values stored in arrays are correct or not, just for testing purpose(will not be in actual code)

Comment: Fixed code indenting

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly here:

```
{sprintf(MyStr,"%c",(unsigned int)StoreUserID[i]);
```

I'm not able to know how you declared the `StoreUserID` array (as `char`? as `int`?) and why did you consistently cast to `unsigned int` (for small positive numbers as `year` or `seconds` it has no meaning) but there are these 2 most probable corrections:

```
{sprintf(MyStr,"%c", StoreUserID[i]);      // for character representation in StoreUserID[]
```

or - and I think that *this is your case* -

```
{sprintf(MyStr,"%c",StoreUserID[i] + '0'); // for numerical one - the conversion is needed
```

Explanation:

Number `0` has character representation `'0'`, which is some number (in ASCII it is `48`).
Number `1` has character representation `'1'`, which is the next number (in ASCII it is `49`).
... and so on.
So you need to add value `'0'` to obtain the *character representation* from the bare number.

Comment: for loop is used just to cross check whether values stored in arrays are correct or not, just for testing purpose(will not be in actual code).Actual problem is using for loop i have confirmed the values I am reading are displayed correctly, but after doing conversion(multiply by 10 and add next array value) the TempHour,Second and Minute shows wrong values. see I've used ClcdPutNum(TempHour) to display on LCD.It shows random values

Comment: Are `TempDay`, `TempMonth`, and `TempYear` displayed correctly? If they are, the problem is with the declaration (ore the use) of `StoreUserID`. How you declared it?